# Aplicación Web Django (corriendo en Apache) se cuelga indefinidamente al importar nltk en views.py

Tags: python-3.x, django, apache, nltk, wampserver

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en Django (3.0.5) y lo desplegué en un Windows Server 2012 usando Wampserver(apache) + mod_wsgi. Hay dos aplicaciones en el proyecto que usan el paquete nltk, al importar este paquete en las vistas el proyecto se queda cargando indefinidamente en el navegador, no muestra ningún error. Agregué esto `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` en el archivo de configuración `htpd.config` de Wampserver como indican en esta publicación [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30715896/django-webapp-on-an-apache2-server-hangs-indefintely-when-importing-nltk-in-vi) y se resolvió parte del problema, pero ahora al ejecutar alguna de las dos aplicaciones que usan el paquete nltk, el navegador muestra `Server Error (500)`

Cabe aclarar que de manera local, es decir, en modo desarrollo funciona a la perfección, el problema viene cuando se despliega en el Servidor, como si Wampserver no pudiera acceder a los archivos nltk que normalmente se encuentran en `C:\Users\usuario_name\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data`

Alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Y en el servidor dónde estará buscando esos archivos? Seguro no es en esa ruta.

Comment: La carpeta `nltk_data` en el servidor también se encuentra en la ruta `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data`, sin embargo, Apache pareciera no poder acceder. También intenté instalar el paquete nltk en la carpeta de archivos del proyecto, en el entorno virtual y en otras ubicaciones, ninguna funcionó. Es como si python o Apache intentarán sí o sí acceder a esa ruta. No sé si hay que indicarsela explícitamente, el tema es cómo?

Comment: Pues es que una cosa es en tu entorno local y otra en el servidor, que no sabes con qué usuario se está ejecutando apache (seguro, segurísimo no es con Administrador; posiblemente sea NETWORK_USER o alguno similar.). Tampoco soy amigo de dejar configuraciones en carpetas de usuarios específicos porque tienen restricciones de seguridad especiales y los procesos del sistema dificilmente las van a ver. Usa una ruta que no esté en carpetas de usuario o en program files.

Comment: Yo tengo acceso al servidor y ejecuto apache como Administrador. La aplicación funciona en local en el mismo servidor. Ya puse los archivos nltk en otra ubicación pero tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como lo indiqué en la pregunta, en el archivo `httpd.config` es necesario agregar:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Adicional, en views.py toca indicarle a Apache la ruta donde se encuentran los archivos nltk, que por defecto están en `C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data` , así :

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk.data.path.append('C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Roaming/nltk_data/')
```